# PhoneGap plist: Can External host be set to ip address?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

Just getting into the PhoneGap development on the Mac.  I have a .NET service hosted on server that does not have DNS assigned. Can I use the ip address in phonegap.plist?  My code works in browser and even as a web version on the actual iphone. Soon as I compile from xcode it seems to not be working (not even on emulator). I ran this js through lint and now im in a spot of bother...  Here is what I am trying to do.

I call GetEstimate on button click:

```
function GetEstimate(From, To) {
"use strict";
varType    = "GET";
varUrl     = "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/service.svc/" + 
"GetBasicEst?pickupPostalCode="+ From + "&dropoffPostalCode="+ To +"";
varContentType    = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
varDataType = "jsonp";
varProcessData = true;
alert("GetEstimate");
new CallService();}

function CallService(){
alert("Inside Call Service");
"use strict";
$.ajax({
       type          : varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
       url           : varUrl, // Location of the service
       data          : varData, //Data sent to server
       contentType   : varContentType, // content type sent to server
       dataType      : varDataType, //Expected data format from server
       processdata   : varProcessData, //True or False
       success       : function(data) {//On Successfull service call
       alert("Success");
       var innerHtml = "";
       var rhigh=data.EstimateHigh;
       var rlow=data.EstimateLow;
       alert(rlow);
       $("#rHigh").html(rhigh);
       $("#rLow").html(rlow);                       
       $("#rHigh").formatCurrency();
       $("#rLow").formatCurrency();                 
       },
       //error: ServiceFailed // When Service call fails
       });}
```

The alert inside CallService does fire then it just seems to stop there...does not call $.ajax(

I could be way out in left field so any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it !!  Drew: I marked you answer about the * as correct. Thank you for that.  I tried a few things to get it working so I will list what I did.  I changed the IP to be a dns resolving name, I took Ip out of Phonegap.plist so just the * was there.  I then added a line of code to ajax call jsonp   :  'callback'.  Not sure which one did it but its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new entry to your plist and have the value be `*`. That's a catch all for all domains. :)

Comment: That is what I do for my own project, but I'm wondering if there could be any security issues doing that ? Any idea ?

Comment: nope you should be fine! The plist just needs to know that it's okay to connect to that IP

Comment: Ok I changed to * but the code still does not seem to work. Like I mentioned it gets to the $.ajax( and just appears to stop.  I have done alerts on both sides of that $.ajax funciton. Any advice would be awesome.  Thankx Drew for advice.

Comment: have you confirmed that you've defined your variables? like varType and such?

Comment: Yes, they are all defined at the top of my .js file.  It's weird that it will work perfectly when run from browser.

Comment: Im still stuck on this, not even sure what to do. Any advice would be helpful. Is my code incorrect, does anybody see a problem?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code again here's the problem. So you always need to white list your domains, but on top of that make sure that your ajax is being called properly.

You are combing the url and data, they need to be separate things. You have the call to varData but you aren't creating that anywhere.

```
function GetEstimate(From, To) {
"use strict";
varType    = "GET";
varUrl     = "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/service.svc/GetBasicEst";

// YOUR DATA
varData = "pickupPostalCode="+ From + "&dropoffPostalCode="+ To;

varContentType    = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
varDataType = "jsonp";
varProcessData = true;
alert("GetEstimate");
new CallService();}

function CallService(){
alert("Inside Call Service");
"use strict";
$.ajax({
       type          : varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
       url           : varUrl, // Location of the service
       data          : varData, //Data sent to server
       contentType   : varContentType, // content type sent to server
       dataType      : varDataType, //Expected data format from server
       processdata   : varProcessData, //True or False
       success       : function(data) {//On Successfull service call
       alert("Success");
       var innerHtml = "";
       var rhigh=data.EstimateHigh;
       var rlow=data.EstimateLow;
       alert(rlow);
       $("#rHigh").html(rhigh);
       $("#rLow").html(rlow);                       
       $("#rHigh").formatCurrency();
       $("#rLow").formatCurrency();                 
       },
       //error: ServiceFailed // When Service call fails
       });}
```

Give that a shot hopefully it helps!

Comment: Well, that was a no go.  Good catch, dumb on my part, but it always worked in a browser test as it was.  Your suggestion still works in a browser test so I am better but still not working on the iphone.  Thanks for your time on this.  Its my first attempt at this phonegap.  I got some great things working but this is the whole key to my app and future apps. It really sucks because I don't even know how to try and fix this.

Comment: So I am wondering if you can use $.ajax() with Phone Gap.  I found this [link](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/42450600/PhoneGap%20Ajax%20Sample). I may try to write this way. Still seems like it should work the way I wrote it.

Comment: you totally can I use it in every phonegap app I make, it's part of my framework. That way in that link is using javascript ajax, very similar. Honestly the answer to your question is going to be something very small. I would look over your code, maybe try simpler code until you see it... It's cases like this where it could be a misplaced , or a stray character or misspelling.

Comment: Wo is me.....Could this possibly be due to my service. Like I have mentioned it works flawless in Chrome on the mac...even safari.  It will not work on the Iphone or the Iphone Emulator.  Anymore suggestions out there.  I'm on the edge here.  Why does it work in the browser?????  NOt on phone??????? grrrrr

Comment: I got it !!  Drew: I marked you answer about the * as correct. Thank you for that.  I tried a few things to get it working so I will list what I did.  I changed the IP to be a dns resolving name, I took Ip out of Phonegap.plist so just the * was there.  I then added a line of code to ajax call jsonp   :  'callback'.  Not sure which one did it but its working now.